# Activity with countDown timer pops up after time is up, how to kill it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have kind of a game with 2 activities: Start Activity (with high score, start button and tutorial button) and main game activity which is is based on countdown timer, when time is up, game returns to start activity.

Problem is when user starts game and then hits home button and goes back to home screen (just leaving game by home button) Everything is ok until time is up, then Start activity appears on screen with lost message.

I've tried various combined methods like `onPause` witch `finish();` inside and so on but it doesn't work or causes app force close.

I can't handle home button click like in `onBackPressed()` which I did in that case.

Is there any way to suspend app and pause all threads while it isn't in foreground?

Comment: could you post your log ?

Comment: D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
D/onTick:: ok
D/onFinish:: ok
D/AppTracker: App Event: start

that's all, nothing unexpected

Comment: Post your error Logcat

Comment: have no errors, remains empty

Comment: it will be error , check again by blue class name and line no.

Comment: There are no errors in logcat, I guess everything works like it's been designed, I just have to know how suspend my app in background

Comment: Did u cancel your timer in the onpause method @ Patroy ?

Comment: best way is handle it in onPause() show your Count down timer code i will fix it

Comment: @A.N.T yes and that actually suspends the app but makes possible to return in suspended session when app is opened again, I would like to see my Start Activity instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two way

**1**

Create global variable like

```
private isInForgrand = false;
```

And in onStop() or onPause() and onResume() change it

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    isInForgrand = false;
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isInForgrand = true;
}
```

And in onFinish() check it

```
@Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(isInForgrand){
               //do what you want  
             }else{
               //your app NOT in Forgrannd
        }
```

**2**

You can cancel CountDownTimer in onStop()

```
@Override
public void onStop() { 
    super.onStop();
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
}
```